# Knockout multiple click bindings do not work with IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, internet-explorer-8

**The problem:**

Multiple click binding do not work in IE8.

**The code:**

```
var Cart = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.books = ko.observableArray();
    self.cds = ko.observableArray();
};

var TheModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.cart = ko.observable(new Cart());
    self.showAddBook = function() {
        self.cart.books.push(/* new book */);
    };
    self.showAddCD = function() {
        self.cart.cds.push(/* new cd */);
    };
};

<div data-bind="with: cart">
    <h1>Books<h1>
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.showAddBook">Add</button>
    <div data-bind="foreach: books">
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span> <!-- book has a name property -->
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <h3>CDs</h3>
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.showAddCD">Add</button>
        <div data-bind="foreach: cds">
            <span data-bind="text: name"></span> <!-- cd has a name property -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**Background:**

Apologies in advance. I don't have access to jsFiddle at work.

I have a deadline to get this piece of work complete which is why I am using knockout with jQuery. Would love to use Angular but can't because we have to support IE8. Would love to use Durandal but I have no experience of it and don't have the time just yet to learn it and finish this piece of work.

A user can create a new book or a new cd and add it to a collection. Not real-world example but reflects the problem I am solving.
A user can click on an Add button, this launches a jQuery dialog which captures some information about a book. This is then saved to the observable array on the model, and the list of books gets updated.

**Question:**

Why does IE8 only seem to bind the first click and not the second? If I click to add a book the dialog is shown. If I click to add a cd, nothing. I have debugged and the function does not get called.

TIA

Comment: *"I don't have access to jsFiddle at work"* What an asinine company policy. But fortunately, you don't need it, Stack Overflow has Stack Snippets. It's the toolbar button just after inserting an image, looks like a page with `<>` on it.

Comment: Please also post your code which shows the actual dialogs!

Comment: +1 for the correct application of the word 'asinine'. It's true I do work for such a company. Thanks also for pointing me to Stack Snippets which I was unaware of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for slightly incorrect example but I had missed one level of nesting. My example is not a true reflection of my complex model and implementation but I worked out the cause of the problem.

My Cart in this example has a `selectedItem` property (an observable) of type object that has the array of books (observable array) and CDs (observable array).

```
var Items = function () { 
    this.books = ko.observableArray(); 
    this.cds = ko.observableArray(); 
}
var Cart = function() { 
    this.selectedItem = ko.observable(new Items()); 
}
var Model = function () { 
    this.cart = new Cart();  
}
```

I was using the knockout '**with**' binding and setting the context to `cart.selectedItem`

```
<div data-bind="with: cart.selectedItem"> ... </div>
```

With this approach I noticed that only the first click (add book) was working. Clicking on Add CD was doing nothing.

I changed the context from `cart.selectedItem` to `cart` and set the **foreach** binding (that displays the list of books and cds) to `selectedItem().books` and `selectedItem().cds` and that worked in IE8 and other browser.

If I change the context using the knockout '**with**' binding back to `cart.selectedItem` then only the first click works.

Hope that helps anyone else who encounters this problem.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, *neither* of them should work, and not on any browser (rather than just not working on IE8), because both functions have the same problem: They don't unwrap `cart`:

```
self.cart.books.push(/* new book */);
//  ^^^^^^
```

`cart` is an observable, so you need:

```
self.cart().books.push(/* new book */);
//       ^^
```

...and similarly for the CDs stuff.

If you fix that, it works (even on IE8):

```js
var Cart = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.books = ko.observableArray();
    self.cds = ko.observableArray();
};

var TheModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.cart = ko.observable(new Cart());
    self.showAddBook = function() {
        self.cart().books.push({name: "New book " + (+new Date())});
    };
    self.showAddCD = function() {
        self.cart().cds.push({name: "New CD " + (+new Date())});
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new TheModel(), document.body);
```

```html
<div data-bind="with: cart">
    <h1>Books<h1>
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.showAddBook">Add</button>
    <div data-bind="foreach: books">
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span> <!-- book has a name property -->
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <h3>CDs</h3>
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.showAddCD">Add</button>
    <div data-bind="foreach: cds">
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span> <!-- cd has a name property -->
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks T.J - that was an mistake on my part but good to highlight something I keep tripping over.